# How can I set the headers of multipart/form-data parts with django.test.Client?

Tags: python, django, multipartform-data, django-testing

Each *part* in a [`multipart/form-data`](http://chxo.com/be2/20050724_93bf.html) document can have its own *headers*, e.g. a section can have a header `Content-Type: text/plain`. These parts can be uploaded files from a web form, for example.

In [the documentation for Django's `UploadedFile` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.content_type), I read

> `UploadedFile.content_type`
>
> The content-type header uploaded with the file (e.g. text/plain or application/pdf). Like any data supplied by the user, you shouldn’t trust that the uploaded file is actually this type. You’ll still need to validate that the file contains the content that the content-type header claims – “trust but verify.”

Okay, I should validate the file against the claimed content type. So of course, now I need to write some tests which test whether my server actually does validate the content type correctly. One such test would be to make a request to my server with `content-type: multipart/form-data`, where at least one part has content which is inconsistent with its content-type.

How can I do this? [The django.test.Client class has a `post` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post) which can send requests with type `multipart/form-data`. The multiple parts of the request body are passed to the method as a dictionary. The keys of this dictionary are strings, and the values are either strings or "file objects".

I wish to understand:

1. how this dictionary is converted to a `multipart/form-data` request body. What are the headers on each part?
2. how to manually set arbitrary headers on each part. How, for instance, can I manually specify a header `Content-Type: text/plain`?

Answer (score 4):

1. The Django test suite [claims](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L157) it'll always use an `application/octet-stream` header for files. That's not actually true though, as the `encode_file` function used actually tries to [guess](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L197) the actual mimetype of the file.
2. This leads to an answer to your second question: before trying to guess the mimetype, the function [looks for](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L200) a `content_type` attribute on the file. You *should* be able to set this to whatever you like and thus overwrite the `Content-Type`.

Comment: This for the answer; this is useful. I'm going to leave it unchecked, though, until someone can point me to a documented Django API to do what I need.

Comment: I was looking for that but couldn't find one :(. But I may just not have been looking hard enough... Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `Client` class inherits from `django.test.client.RequestFactory` ([src](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L221))  and effectively and you can see in the `Client`'s `post` definition that it's basically a call to `super`, so you can refer to the `RequestFactory` [post definition](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L305). By default, this in turn calls [_encode_data](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L272) which uses [encode_multipart](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L151), which, as you've noticed, specifies "multipart/form-data".

Here, you can see some headers are specified for each part (e.g, `Content-Disposition`), however I do not see a way to specify a `Content-Type` header (or any specific header) for each part.